# FQL get fbid without parsing album link

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I can't find any answer to this: I'd like to get the fbid of all my Facebook album but the only way is parsing the parameter "link" of this FQL query, as you can see here:

```
var query = {
    "query1": 'select link,photo_count from album where owner = me() and photo_count>0',
        "query2": 'select "" from photo_tag where subject = me()'
};
FB.api('/fql', {
    'q': query
}, function (response) {
    var albums = response.data[0].fql_result_set;
    var tagged_count = response.data[1].fql_result_set.length;
    var albumsInfo = [];
    $(albums).each(function (index, value) {
        if (value.link === null) return;
        albumsInfo.push({
            id: value.link.replace(/.*fbid=([0-9]+)&id=.*&aid=.*/g, "$1"),
            count: value.photo_count
        });
    });
    albumsInfo.push({
        id: "tagged",
        count: tagged_count
    });
    if ($.isFunction(success)) success(albumsInfo);
});
```

Is there a way to get the fbid directly without graph api?

Comment: Why can't you just use the `aid` field of the [album FQL table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album/)? - that's documented as being the album ID